# How to get packet count in a time interval from wireshark logs

Tags: filtering, wireshark, broadcast

I am trying to inspect wireshark logs at the moment captured from an in-field system. We have some protection internally for broadcast messages on embedded devices to ensure they dont get swamped at the application layer by too many broadcasts. We suspect this protection is at the root issue of this problem we are seeing.

However, I am looking through the logs trying to figure out how many times there are more than 10 messages in a 10mS interval.

Is there anyway to automatically do this in wireshark? I have been processing manually using the filters to determine what messages are going to which destinations and which sources, but I am unsure how to have (essentially) a sliding time window to highlight the number of messages within the defined interval.

Is this something I have to do outside of Wireshark? Process the log in csv or similar?

I have tried to google sliding window/timeframe filters in wireshark, but nothing relevant comes up, only filtering tutorials in Wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the IO Graph in the Statistics menu to do this. I was able to set the time intervals to 10mS, and apply a filter for broadcasts/messages that were applicable